# To what data type group belongs callable and iterable in php?

Tags: php, types

In php we have some native data types, like:

- Scalar Data Types: integer, string, Floating-Point Numbers or
  Doubles, Boolean
- Composite Data Type: array, object
- Special Data Types: Null, resource, in php8.0 it should be also
  never/void/true/false

But to what group can we set callable and iterable? Is it composite data types?

Comment: I've never heard the term "composite" referred to data types in PHP. The important categorisation in PHP is the context where you can use them. Some types are used by variables, some types are allowed in type hints, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So callable and iterable are pseudo-types.